# Angular JS Dynamic Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, generics, model, scope

What I'm trying to do here is when I type in a text in the `MainField`, I want `DateField` and `NumberField` to be enabled. I want the `$scope.enableSubFields` to be generic so it can be used as a utility. ( The controller does not work, Im only trying to show what I kind of like want :) )

Here's my HTML  :

```
        <div>
            <label>IF THIS HAS TEXT THEN ENABLE DATE AND NUMBER FIELD</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="MainField" ng-change="enableSubFields('MainField','Subfield')"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>DATE FIELD</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="DateField" ng-disabled="Subfield"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>NUMBER FIELD:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="NumberField" ng-disabled="Subfield"/>
        </div>
```

Heres my Controller

```
$scope.Subfield= true;
$scope.enableSubFields = function (mainField, subfield) {

    if ($scope + '.' + mainField != "") {
        $scope + '.' + subfield = false;
    } else {
        $scope + '.' + subfield = true;            
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a bracket notation to access dynamic properties of an object. So your code should be:

```
$scope.enableSubFields = function(mainField, subfield) {
    if ($scope[mainField] !== "") {
        $scope[subfield] = false;
    } else {
        $scope[subfield] = true;
    }
};
```

or shorter:

```
$scope.enableSubFields = function(mainField, subfield) {
    $scope[subfield] = $scope[mainField] == "";
};
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/IbVzrPFEf624JiG6hIrC?p=preview

Comment: Thaaaaaaaank you!! this gives me more ideas of how I can play with angular. Thanks!! + that shorter code is cool O_O

Comment: Glad to help, in general you can play with javascript using such approaches.

Comment: How about if i want to clear the text field when it is disabled? I think I can do it in jquery but is there a way in angular to select the model of the text field so I can set its value to an empty string?

Comment: @ElementaryStudentProgramming Then I would go with directive. http://plnkr.co/edit/IbVzrPFEf624JiG6hIrC?p=preview